# Yii2 web url without using setAlias

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii2 app but no ability to edit the config files to utilize setAlias.

If my domain is example.com, and my Yii application is in `/my-app` directory, then what would be the Yii command to return the following string:

```
http://example.com/my-app/
```

`Yii::getAlias('@app')` returns

```
/httpdocs/my-app
```

Many posts exist but all I've found is suggestions either based on Yii1 or using setAlias in application config.

Comment: Yii::getAlias('@web') ?

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli  `Yii::getAlias('@web')` only returns `/my-app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo can use a simple urlHelper (for absolute url)

```
use yii\helpers\Url;


echo Url::to(['/'], true );
```

Comment: If you want absolute URL, `echo Url::to(['/'], true);`

Comment: @scaisEdge `Yii:$app->$homeUrl` is not correct and `Yii::$app->homeUrl` just returns `/my-app`